# Spring boot app failed to start with error "Application required a single bean, but 2 were found"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mqtt

I am writing a Spring Boot application using the `spring-integration-mqtt` dependency where I am using a `CommandLineRunner` bean to start the `MQTTSubscriber` at application launch.

However, when I run the application, I get the following error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-01-26 01:48:40.386 ERROR 59171 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Field MessageListener in im.sma.mqtt.mqttclient.DemoApplication required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - messageListener: defined in file [/Users/sma/sandbox/slidecab/mqtt/mqtt-client/target/classes/im/sma/mqtt/mqttclient/config/MessageListener.class]
    - integrationHeaderChannelRegistry: defined in null
Action:
Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

I've noticed that the error disappears when I remove the following part from my code:

```
@Autowired
Runnable MessageListener;

@Bean
public CommandLineRunner schedulingRunner(TaskExecutor executor) {
    return new CommandLineRunner() {
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            executor.execute(MessageListener);
        }
    };
}
```

This is my `DemoApplication` class where the error happens:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Autowired
    Runnable MessageListener;

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner schedulingRunner(TaskExecutor executor) {
        return new CommandLineRunner() {
            public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
                executor.execute(MessageListener);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Additionally, I also have the following `AppConfig` class to set up a `TaskExecutor`:

```
@Component
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    }
}
```

And this is the `MessageListener` bean it couldn't autowire:

```
@Component
public class MessageListener implements Runnable {

    @Autowired
    MQTTSubscriberBase subscriber;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            subscriber.subscribeMessage("demoTopic2019");
        }

    }
}
```

Additionally I have the  following configuration to  set up the `MQTTSubscriber`:

```
public abstract class MQTTConfig {
    protected final String broker = "localhost";
    protected final int qos = 2;
    protected Boolean hasSSL = false; /* By default SSL is disabled */
    protected Integer port = 1883; /* Default port */
    protected final String userName = "guest" ;//"testUserName";
    protected final String password = "guest";//"demoPassword";
    protected final String TCP = "tcp://";
    protected final String SSL = "ssl://";

    protected abstract void config(String broker, Integer port, Boolean ssl, Boolean withUserNamePass);

    protected abstract void config();
}
```

```java
public interface MQTTSubscriberBase {
    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MQTTSubscriberBase.class);

    public void subscribeMessage(String topic);
    public void disconnect();
}
```

```java
@Component
public class MQTTSubscriber extends MQTTConfig implements MqttCallback, MQTTSubscriberBase {
    private String brokerUrl = null;
    private String colon = ":";
    private String clientId = "demoClient2";

    private MqttClient client = null;
    private MqttConnectOptions options = null;
    private MemoryPersistence persistence = null;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MQTTSubscriber.class);

    public MQTTSubscriber() {
        this.config();
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
        logger.info("Connection lost");
    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
        String time = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("********************************************************");
        System.out.println("Message arrived at " + time + "Topic: " + topic + " Message: " + new String(message.getPayload()));
        System.out.println("********************************************************");
        System.out.println();
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
        // Not required for subscriber
    }


    @Override
    public void subscribeMessage(String topic) {
        try {
            this.client.subscribe(topic, this.qos);
        } catch (MqttException exception) {
            logger.error("ERROR", exception);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void disconnect() {
        try {
            this.client.disconnect();
        } catch (MqttException exception) {
            logger.error("ERROR: ", exception);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void config(String broker, Integer port, Boolean ssl, Boolean withUserNamePass) {
        String protocol = this.TCP;
        if (true == ssl) {
            protocol = this.SSL;
        }

        this.brokerUrl = protocol + broker + this.colon + port;
        this.persistence = new MemoryPersistence();
        this.options = new MqttConnectOptions();

        try {
            this.client = new MqttClient(this.brokerUrl, clientId, persistence);
            this.options.setCleanSession(true);
            if (true == withUserNamePass) {
                if (this.password != null) {
                    this.options.setPassword(this.password.toCharArray());
                }
                if (this.userName != null) {
                    this.options.setUserName(this.userName);
                }
            }
            this.client.connect(this.options);
            this.client.setCallback(this);
        }
        catch(MqttException exception) {
            this.logger.error("ERROR ", exception);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void config() {
        this.brokerUrl = this.TCP + this.broker + this.colon + this.port;
        this.persistence = new MemoryPersistence();
        this.options = new MqttConnectOptions();

        try {
            this.client = new MqttClient(brokerUrl, clientId, persistence);
            this.options.setCleanSession(true);
            this.client.connect(options);
            this.client.setCallback(this);
        }
        catch(MqttException exception) {
            logger.error("ERROR", exception);
        }
    }

}
```

And these are the dependencies I'm using:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>
  <groupId>im.sma.mqtt</groupId>
  <artifactId>mqtt-client</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>demo</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-integration-mqtt</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Why can I not inject the bean and what action should I take?

Comment: The error message already says how you can solve it, so what exactly are you asking? Is there something not clear?

Comment: One possible  solution was to declare on of the two beans  as @Primary, I have tried this option still does not work. The way I am using CommandLineRunner interface  is very command execute code on application launch and keep it running.

Comment: Did you try adding `@Qualifier("messageListener")` next  to the `@Autowired` annotation for the `messageListener` field?

Comment: @g00glen00b Yes  I have  tried  it and it works, great thanks a lot you are a life saver.

Comment: @g00glen00b I have also found another solution, if  use  direct dependency of  paho client i.e.org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3 (from eclipse repository  at https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/) instead of spring-integration-mqtt then every thing  works fine even without using @Qualifier("messageListener") annotation.

Comment: @g00glen00b it will really be helpful if you can explain the "@Qualifier" solution  in context of mentioned problem.

Comment: I've created a detailed answer covering an explanation of the solutions Spring proposed, and in addition a few solutions that may also work, just like removing the Spring integration library as you mentioned.

Comment: @g00glen00b, yes  I  have  read  your detailed  reply, by the way  why  I am getting negative  scores for this  question?

Comment: I haven't downvoted you, but my assumption is that people might think this is a low effort question because (1) the solution is within the error message (2) there is a lot of code within the question that isn't really related to the actual cause. This also the reason why I initially asked if something wasn't clear about the error message. If you don't know what the `@Primary`/`@Qualifier` thing means, then the error message isn't exactly helpful, and that appeared to be the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that you're using a pretty generic interface for your autowiring, being `Runnable`.

Due to that, it seems there are two beans that exist that match the `Runnable` interface:

1. One being the `MessageListener` class you created yourself
2. Another one being the [`DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/api/org/springframework/integration/channel/DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry.html), exposed as a bean called `integrationHeaderChannelRegistry`. Presumably it's being exposed because you have Spring integration on your classpath.

The issue is that due to this, the Spring IoC container can't figure out what bean it should inject, and it provides some solutions.

#### Marking one of the beans as `@Primary`

This can be used in scenarios where one of those beans will be used in 99% of the scenarios. By marking the `MessageListener` class as `@Primary`, it will take priority when trying to inject it, for example:

```
@Primary // Add this
@Component
public class MessageListener implements Runnable {
    // ...
}
```

#### Updating the consumer to accept multiple beans

This scenario is useful when you want a reference to all `Runnable` beans. In your case, that's probably not the solution, but in some situations you may want to get all beans of a certain type. To do that, you could do:

```
@Autowired
private List<Runnable> runnables; // Change the type to List<Runnable>
```

#### Using `@Qualifier` to identify the bean

Another possibility is to use `@Qualifier` to specify the exact name of the bean you want to inject. In your case, you can choose between `messageListener` or `integrationHeaderChannelRegistry`. For example:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("messageListener")
private Runnable mesageListener;
```

This is probably the best solution in your case that's being proposed.

---

There are also a few additional solutions I want to provide as well.

#### Using a specific type

If you change the type of the autowired field to `MessageListener`, there's no confusion to which bean that should be injected, due to there only being a single bean of type `MessageListener`:

```
@Autowired
private MessageListener mesageListener;
```

#### Not using the Spring integration library

The code you've shown so far has nothing to do with Spring integration. If your only goal is to set up an MQTT client, you might want to consider to drop the `spring-integration-mqtt` package and use a simple MQTT client implementation like [Eclipse Paho](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/) in stead.

Since the other bean was being created automatically because you added the `spring-integration-mqtt` library, removing it will stop causing the bean from being created, and that will solve the issue as well.

Comment: Thanks @g00glen00b for  detailed  reply, this  was really helpful. I have mentioned the  last  solution in  my previous  comment i.e  the issue  does not occur  if  I  add direct  dependency of Eclipse Paho Java client library. Once again thanks  a  lot for your detailed  reply with all the technical details.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem in my code for a week, and today I've found that juste because I've given the same name to two metods :

```
   @Bean(name = "sqlServer")
public DataSource sqlServerDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.ds-sql.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.ds-sql.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.ds-sql.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.ds-sql.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean(name = "sqlJdbc")
public JdbcTemplate sqlServerDataSource(@Qualifier("sqlServer") DataSource dsSqlServer) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dsSqlServer);
}
```

Hope this will help the persons having the same case.

Good Luck